# Catalog table list into web browser

Tags: mapinfo, table, workspace

I'm looking to do some cataloging of both workspaces and table metadata - I want to cycle through a workspace and pick up the table names and associate those with the wrokspace name (I can then track where data is being used) but then display the results in a web page similarly, I would like to get the metadata from a table into a web browser - any pointers to some code to do this, don't mind what language.